# Angular Table Order Pipe not resetting initial state

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, html-table, pipe

this is actually my first time ever asking something here.

Problem: I made a pipe to reorder a specific column in my application (alphabetical order)
it can have 3 statuses -1, 0 and 1, where 0 is the default initial status. but, after i reorder my table and get my status back to 0 it does not reverse it back but keeps the current order

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ExternalUploads } from 'src/app/model/external/ExternalUploads ';
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderpipe',
  pure: false
})
export class OrderPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(uploads: ExternalUploads [], colstat: any) {
    console.log(colstat.value);
    
    let result : ExternalUploads[] = uploads;

    if(colstat.value!= 0)
        if(colstat.value=== 1)
            result.sort((a,b) => a.name=== b.name? 0 : a.name< b.name? -1 : 1);
        else 
        result.sort((a,b) => a.name=== b.name? 0 : a.name> b.name? -1 : 1);

    return result; 
  }
}
```

I also tried returning "uploads" instead of "result" and the table is actually changing its order (even if it actually shouldn't?)

What am i supposed to do to make it work?

(i must use a pipe, using Angular 11).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do this :

```
if (colstat.value=== 1)
        result.sort((a,b) => a.name=== b.name? 0 : a.name< b.name? -1 : 1);
else if (colstat.value=== -1) 
    result.sort((a,b) => a.name=== b.name? 0 : a.name> b.name? -1 : 1);
```

Comment: Yeah, i had tried it, i think i found the problem: the original array of objects was getting modified when modifying result.
Fixed it by assigning [...uploads] to result and it is working fine now, thank you really much